# Freeradius, CoovaChilli CP, disable account for the rest of the day

Tags: mysql, networking, freeradius, captivenetwork, coovachilli

I'm using CoovaChilli and Freeradius with mysql to implement CaptivePortal. So far everything works fine. You can login with user account from DB and access the internet. Then I needed to set time limit for accounts and it also works fine, but after it ends my session I can just logout and login with same account and continue using internet. What I need to do is to allow accounts to be used only ONCE a day. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Thanks,
Nemanja

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `Login-time:` attribute